# django bulk create with many=True, need save foreignkey from a different field in foreign table?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

## Models

```
class User(models.Model):
  email = models.EmailField()


class Session(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey()
  name = models.TextField()

class SessionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  email = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
  fields=['name', 'email']
```

I need to create multiple objects with session serializer but how to save the user by using the email that is passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SlugRelatedField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield)

```
class SessionSerializer:
  email = SlugRelatedField(source='user', slug_field='email', queryset=User.objects.all())
  class Meta: 
      fields=['name', 'email']
```

Note that `email` model's field should be unique:

```
class User(models.Model):
  email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

Comment: So email needs to be a primary key or not?

Comment: @JissRaphel no, it's not required. But it should be unique.

Comment: is there any way to get the user?

Comment: @JissRaphel SlugRelatedField will find user automatically. If you need to create new user use writable nested relation.